# How to "Add Service Reference" in .NET Standard project with Xamarin?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, xamarin, prism

I am developing a mobile application with Xamarin.Forms / Prism.

I used PCL Profile 44 until now.
That is because PCL Profile 44 contains the function of WCF.

Today, I created a project using Prism Template Pack 2.0.
A project was created with .NET Standard instead of .NET Framework.

When .NET Framework and PCL Profile 44, there was an item "Add Service Reference" in the PCL project, in Visual Studio.
However, when it comes to .NET Standard, that item does not exist anywhere.

How do I run "Add Service Reference"?

---

The following site is introduced to the method of WCF access with Xamarin.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/

But I do not want to use this method.
In this way, you will create a WCF access process in your Android / iOS project. And here we are using SLsvcUtil.exe.
When PCL Profile 44 is used, you can write WCF access processing in PCL project. Also, SLsvacUtil.exe is unnecessary.

I tried the following plug-in, but an error occurred when adding service reference.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WCFCORETEAM.VisualStudioWCFConnectedService